# GWT on Chrome - Uncaught TypeError: Object #<a Document> has no method 'write'

Tags: jsf, gwt, google-chrome

I have this JSF page trying to load a GWT app.
The page works fine on Firefox and IE but on Chrome I get the following error
when I check with developer tools. 
Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'write'
I tried to change CONTENT_TYPE of the page as read in other posts but no luck.

Here is the page,

www.paste.to/v/hngl4nys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the `<f:view contentType="text/html"><html>...</html></f:view>` tag around the html page.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051227/seam-gwt-pageflow-transition/4051685#4051685) for an example.